# What are some remarkable regional dialects based on German?

Tags: dialect, regional

There is a regional slang dialect in the region of Brno (South Moravia, close to Austrian border) called [*Hantec*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hantec). Lexically it draws on German, Austrian German, Yiddish, Romish, and perhaps some other languages for all its quirks, some morphology follows the South Moravian dialects, but overall its grammar is based on Czech. Hantec (including its written form) is rather hard to comprehend to non-speakers. It seems to be slowly disappearing, although many lexical items persist and are used by the general population in the city (e.g., *koc* (a young woman) is supposed to mirror a typical Austrian pronunciation of *Katze*).

I wonder whether there are other such regional dialects <s>based (or based to a large extent) on German</s> influenced by German in an analogous (i.e., mainly lexical) fashion.

Comment: Perhaps not based on..., but the *Silesian* is spoken in Poland: 
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlesisch_(polnischer_Dialekt)

Comment: Hantec is not a "regional dialect based on German". It is a dialect of Czech with loanwords from German and other languages. By contrast, Yiddish is structurally German, with loan words from Hebrew and other languages.

Comment: Brünn/Brno was for a very long time a bilingual town. People used to speak Czech and German. German was the language of the upper class (or who wanted to seem as upper class) while the majority of the workers was speaking Czech. Hantec is not a German dialect. It is a Czech dialect with tons of German loanwords. So Hantec is not an example for what you are asking (it's not a »*remarkable regional dialect based on German*«).

Comment: @fdb, as I understand it, the question does not stipulate that Hantec would be an example of a "regional dialect based on German", but gives it as an example of a "regional dialect based on Czech”.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I did not say Hantec was a dialect of German as far as I can recollect. As for the upper/lower class distinction made in your comment, while to a large extent true, it is pertinent not just to Brno but to the whole region of Bohemia and Moravia (at least): German was the language of the educated classes and the _lingua franca_ of the Austrian Empire (just as French, for example, was used in Britain after the Norman Conquest). .....

Comment: (cont'd) ..... What is more relevant, I think, is the fact that there was a large population in Brno whose _first language_ was German; another relevant fact is the proximity of Vienna -- the Viennese argot was a major influence to Hantec.

Comment: Africa: Namibian German, Namibian Black German, Nataler Deutsch 
North America: Amana German, Alsatian German, Bernese German, Hutterite German, Pennsylvania German, Texas German, Wisconsin German
South America: Alemán Coloniero, Argentinian Swiss German, Belgranodeutsch, Brazilian German (Ostpommersch, Paraná Volga German and Riograndenser Hunsrückisch)
Oceania: Barossa German
Non-specific:
Plautdietsch, Yiddish

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:German_dialects